# "this" within Google Apps Script class method returns null?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My first time asking a question on Stack Overflow! Kinda embarrassed that I'm asking this because it's probably so simple, but I just can't figure it out....

I am trying to use create a custom class where I can inherit some of the GAS Spreadsheet class functions:

```
class Division {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    this.getRange = this.getRange.bind(this)
  }  
    getRange(range) {
      Logger.log(this)
      Logger.log(range)
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.name)
      return sheet.getRange()
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run one of the scripts, the code threw me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null` when I encounter a line of code like this:
`const Nscore = Central.getRange('B2')`

The log being:

```
{getRange=function () { [native code] }, name=null, sheet=null}
B2
```

How do I make the `this` in the class method point to the context within the class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, I was stupid.

Turned out I just forgot to add in the argument when I defined n instance of the class.

I had

```
Central = new Division()
```

when I was supposed to write

```
Central = new Division('Central')
```